# SOLR case insensitivity within group

Tags: solr

I have a field in the managed-schema that looks like this:

```
<field name="Title" type="strings">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="select">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
</field>
```

If I search for the word **spiderman** I get 15 results. However the minute I search for **(Title:spiderman)** I get 0 results. I need to be able to do sub groups in the query hence why the first option isn't an option. Am I missing something obvious?

Equally a search for **SpiderMan** returns 15 results however even with a fuzzy search and Title `(Title:spiderman~)` I only get 1 result.

Comment: are you mixing the fieldType and field together...? As I know fieldType should be defined seperate and field separate..

Comment: I'm really a beginner at SOLR so please expound ...

Comment: That is what gets generated in the managed-schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these entries in the schema.xml file.
Define fieldType like below :

```
<fieldType name="title" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Define field like below :

```
<field name="title" type="title" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```